# How to execute functions sequentially in the background thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, scheduler

I'm working in making an Android Chat App which has the feature of selecting and sending multiple images from the App. I use RxJava to run the send function in background thread.

I fetch multiple images from the gallery and put them in `for` loop one by one as shown in the below code. The problem I'm facing is that the order of images is not getting preserved.

This is the code I use to send multiple images.

```
public void onMessageSent(String messageText, ArrayList<Attachment> attachments) {
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(attachments)) {
            Stream.of(attachments)
                    .forEach(attachment -> chatInteractor.sendAttachment(mConversationId, attachment, messageParticipants, quoteMessageId)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(MapUtils::dummyfunction, errorHandler::logErrorViaInstance));

        }
    }
```

`messageText` contains the message which has to be sent with the images, the ArrayList `attatchments` contains all the images with their data and `chatInteractor.sendAttachment` is a  `public` function with a return type `Maybe<Message>`.

The order of images is maintained in `attatchments`. But when all the images are being sent in the background thread `Schedulers.io()`, some images are getting sent earlier and some later.

How to maintain the order? What code changes should I make?

I tried changing `subscribeOn` to `Schedulers.single()` and `Schedulers.trampoline()`, but none of them are helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RxJava directly to make a sequence of uploads:

```java
Observable.fromIterable(attachments)
.concatMapMaybe(attachment -> 
     chatInteractor.sendAttachment(
         mConversationId, attachment, messageParticipants, quoteMessageId
     )
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(MapUtils::dummyfunction, errorHandler::logErrorViaInstance);
```

Comment: Will the iterations happen one after other(next one when predecessor is done)? or iterates all at a time?

Comment: `concatMap` ensures only one `sendAttachment` is running at a time and in order.

Comment: Your code is giving an error: `no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Maybe<Message> conforms to ObservableSource<? extends R>`
on code inside `concactMap(....)`
Can you check? I think the syntax is little wrong.


`I have changed into (Function<Attachment, ObservableSource<Message>>)attachment ->`


But it is saying Maybe cannot be converted into ObservableSource.

Comment: Use `concatMapMaybe`.

Comment: extremely thank you, it's working as expected (once one image is sent, the next one is sent later)
But, the whole process is delayed

Comment: If I choose to send 9 images, one by one is loading, it takes around 10 sec for that 9 images to be sent. Can something be done there? Or I have to change the whole implementation?

Comment: You wanted ordered upload. If you want concurrent upload and keep some sort of ordering, you'd have to associate an index with each image uploaded and when you download them, order by that index.